# Why is the UITapGestureRecognizer never getting called with state began?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

If you assign a **UITapGestureRecognizer** to a **UIView** the **UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan** doesn't appear when the user has touched the view.

```
// Tap

_tapGestureRecognizer =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(tap:)];
    
[_someView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Instead the recognizer jumps straight to **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** when the user performs the tap.

I have to change that view to a **UIButton** and listen to the touchDown method.

```
_someButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    
[_someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    
[self addSubview: _someButton];
```

I don't like changing the **UIView** to a **UIButton** just for this.

Can I use the UITapGestureRecognizer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) docs clearly tell to expect a callback for all states.

> For gesture recognition, the specified number of fingers must tap the view a specified number of times. **Although taps are discrete gestures, they are discrete for each state of the gesture recognizer. The system sends the associated action message when the gesture begins and then again for each intermediate state until (and including) the ending state of the gesture.** Code that handles tap gestures should test for the state of the gesture, for example:
>
> ```
> func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
>     if sender.state == .ended {
>         // handling code
>     }
> }
> ```

Hower it makes little to no sense (specially in case of single tap recognizer). You touched a view (that had the tap gesture added to it), you haven't yet lifted your finger, moved it etc. System can't know at the time of `.touchDown` event that this interaction is going to turn into a successful recognition of a tap (which requires lifting the finger up).

Essentially `UITapGestureRecognizer` (for a single touch tap) is a `.touchDown + .touchUp` combination. If anything else happens after `.touchDown` like a drag (`.touchDragInside` OR `.touchDragExit`), it may lead to successful recognition of a pan gesture (tableView scrolling etc.)

You can think of `UITapGestureRecognizer` **roughly equivalent** to `.touchUpInside` event for a button. A `.touchUpInside` event for a button doesn't call your function for `.touchDown` event, It is only possible to receive that event by explicitly asking for the same.

##### Why do the docs say so?

> Maybe system is able to identify the `.began` state for other scenarios
>
> 1. a multi-tap gesture - double/triple tap (see [`UITapGestureReconizer.numberOfTapsRequired`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/1623581-numberoftapsrequired))
> 2. a multi-touch tap - 2/3 finger tap (see [`UITapGestureReconizer.numberOfTouchesRequired`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/1623580-numberoftouchesrequired))
>
> You have to test other scenarios for this if you want to know more.